# Date format not working properly in Ruby

Tags: ruby

My string is: `"02-19-2016"`, which is date in MM-DD-YYYY format. It's giving proper result for some scenarios, but for some, its failing like:

```
@query="02-19-2016"
d, m, y = @query.split '-'
# => ["02", "19", "2016"] 
Date.valid_date? y.to_i, m.to_i, d.to_i
# => false
```

Can someone give any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
d, m, y = @query.split '-'
```

to

```
m, d, y = @query.split '-'
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Date.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) was build to parse strings by a certain pattern:

```
require 'date'

Date.strptime("02-19-2016", '%m-%d-%Y')
#<Date: 2016-02-19 ((2457438j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'date'

m, d, y = '02-19-2016'.split('-').map(&:to_i)
# => [2, 19, 2016]

Date.valid_date? y, m, d
# => true

date = Date.civil(y, m, d)
# => #<Date: 2016-02-19 ((2457438j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```